# MATLAB listener ignores some part of my code and draws an unwanted figure

Tags: java, matlab, user-interface, listener

I have a GUI that takes values from a slider and makes plots using them. I'm using a listener to get all the plots for all the values along the way when the slider is dragged. It is working, however, I have a little problem.

```
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
%unnecessary code here
D_son = evalin('base','D_son');
axes(handles.axes1);
plot(handles.axes1, D_son);
xlim([1,360]) %LINE ONE
set(gca,'XTick',[1 45 90 135 180 225 270 315 360])%LINE TWO
addlistener(handles.slider1,'ContinuousValueChange',@(hObject, event) slider1_Callback(hObject,   eventdata, handles));
My problem is, when I drag the slider;
```

1. It places the graph on the correct axes, however, it brings up a blank Figure page.
2. It completely ignores LINE ONE and LINE TWO I marked up there.

Other than these two, it works just fine. How can I fix these problems?

Comment: My guess would be that the blank figure appears because of the call to gca. I once had a similar problem and it fixed it. Also I think you need to add the "addlistener(handles.slider1...)" line in the create function of slider1 and not in its callback.

Comment: thank you for your answer benoit_11. now here's what I've done: about 1. I tried completely deleting gca part so the code was like set('XTick'...) and that gave an error. I'm a matlab rookie so I guess that's not how I should have done that. well, then I tried completely deleting that line, so no more set(gca...), it still brings up the blank figure. and about 2.: I cut and pasted addlistener line under create function, it gave an error, which is "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.". again, it completely ignores those two lines, no xticks no xlim, nothing.

Comment: The blank figure appearing is due to the fact that when you call gca, Matlab does not associate it with an existing axes so it creates one, blank. Right now I can't test anything because I don't have access to Matlab but be aware that the callback function for a slider executes only when you release the button, and not as you drag it. Thus if the listener object is in this callback, it will likely generate strange behavior so make sure to not include the "addlistener..." in the callback, but only in the Create function. I'll try to be of more help as soon as I recover my laptop sorry :)

Comment: hello and thank you again benoit_11. I thought I was supposed to add some piece of code in callback function to make it refresh momentarily, didn't know it was the create function that does that. I'll try and see what I can do with create function. as for problem number 1, I'll see how I can get rid of gca. it is odd though, as I said, even without any gca or anything it still creates a blank figure. I'll be looking forward to your next response and in the meantime I'll see what I can do. thanks.

Comment: Hey there, just a quick update here. I have received some help from another website (not sure if it is okay to name other websites on this website, so I'll just not share it yet), and that solved my problem. If somebody can inform me about whether or not I should share the help I've got, so if somebody else encounters the same problem they can benefit from that post on that other website, I can share the link here to my topic. But yeah as the result, you were right, I was putting creating the listener under the wrong callback. thank you again for your repsonses and help.

Comment: Ok no problem! I think it's fine if you share the info. You can write/accept an answer for your own question so people will have access to it in the future.

Comment: Alright then. and it is from matlab's official user forums so I think it's okay to share the direct link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the help I have received from matlab's official user forums. I'm putting this here so other people can benefit in the future. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/144493-listener-ignores-some-part-of-the-code-and-creates-unwanted-figure